# CQLSH "DESCRIBE TYPES" command not working

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am new to CQLSH. I want to see all the user defined types in a keyspace and I found the "DESCRIBE TYPES" command.

But when I ran it, it shows:

```
beaconpoc@cqlsh:test> describe TYPES;

list[i] not a string for i in 0
```

Would could be wrong? Thank you!

Comment: looks like, this issue is resolved in 3.10 - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12914

Answer (score 1):

To describe **TYPE** for all **KEYSPACES**:

```
beaconpoc@cqlsh> DESC TYPES
```

To describe **TYPE** of a particular **KEYSPACE**:

```
beaconpoc@cqlsh> DESC TYPE keyspace_name.type_name;
```